# A fast way to extract similar data in array

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array

I don't exactly know how to state my problem below in a question so please bear with me.

**The problem:**

I have a multi-dimension array that looks like this:

```
$raw_list[0]['123','foo','foo1','300']
$raw_list[1]['456','foo2','foo3','4']
$raw_list[2]['123','foo4','foo5','67']
$raw_list[3]['456','foo6','foo7','34']
```

This usually gets very large (can possibly get to over a thousand indexes?)

What I want to do with it is to separate all records with the same 0th element value in **$raw_list[nth][0]** and operate on each group such that...

```
$raw_list[0]['123','foo','foo1','300']
$raw_list[2]['123','foo4','foo5','67']
```

Then I operate on this group to get various statistical info. For example, the sum of element values '300' and '67' and so on.

**Current solution:**

At the moment this is how my code actually looks like.

```
my @anum_group = ();
@die_raw_list = sort {$a->[0] <=> $b->[0]} @die_raw_list;

my $anum_reference = @die_raw_list[0][0];

for my $row (0..$#die_raw_list) 
{
    if ($die_raw_list[$row][0] == $anum_reference)
    {
        push @anum_group, $die_raw_list[$row];
    }
    else
    {
        # Profile ANUM group
        # ... operation to get statistical info on group here


        # Initialize next ANUM group
        $anum_reference = $die_raw_list[$row][0];
        @anum_group = ();
        push @anum_group, $die_raw_list[$row];
    }
}

# Profile last ANUM group
#  ... operation to get statistical info on group here
```

**Final thoughts and question:**

I realized that on very large data this tends to be very slow and I want to speed things up.

I'm new with Perl and don't know how to best solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the amazing solutions. I'll be trying them out now and get back here with the results.

Comment: Just tested out the suggestions below and I got it to work. Again, thanks to everyone who posted their ideas. :)

Comment: Don't write "solved" in titles. Or tags. Or thanks!

Comment: Woops sorry I didn't know. Anyhow thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thousand indexes is not that many...  What makes you think your code is slow?  And what part is slow?

If the first element is that important, you could re-arrange your data structure to index it that way in the first place:

```
my %raw_list = ('123' => [['foo', 'foo1', '300'],
                          ['foo4', 'foo5', '67']],
                '456' => [['foo2', 'foo3', '4'],
                          ['foo6', 'foo7', '34']]);
```

You could build it dynamically something like this:

```
my %raw_list;
my $elt0 = '123';
my @rec = ('foo', 'foo1', '300');
push @{$raw_list{$elt0}}, \@rec;
```

And process it like this:

```
foreach my $elt0 (keys %raw_list) {
    my $records = $raw_list{$elt0};
    foreach my $rec (@$records) {
        # Now $elt0 is (e.g.) '123'
        # and $rec->[0] is 'foo', $rec->[1] is 'foo1', $rec->[2] is '300'
    }
}
```

To be really clean, you would want to encapsulate all of this in an object...

Comment: I like this solution. I'm figuring out how to work this out on my code.
Btw, the data I'm processing here comes from previously filtered text files (usually around 10~200mb at the moment) on the same program. The ones that gets into the $die_raw_list are the ones that I needed.

Comment: Question though... is push_back a hash function? Can't seem to find it over the web.

Comment: Whoops.  Too long since I hacked Perl.  Should be just "push".  I have fixed the sample code (and cleaned up a bit of the syntax).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to grab the records with the same value in the first value in the second dimension, `123` in your example, sort them by the other fields, and then compare certain values inside them.

This can all be accomplished by sorting by the different values:

```
my @sorted = sort { 
    $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] || # <=> for numerical
    $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] || # cmp for non-numerical
    $a->[2] cmp $b->[2] ...etc
} @die_raw_list;
```

Then you can simply loop your way through your data, picking out the values you need.

If you only want some of the values, you can do a partial selection with something simple like:

```
my @partial;
for my $refs (@die_raw_list) {
    push @partial, $ref if $ref->[0] == '123';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your data into a hash indexed by the first element and then quickly go through each element of the hash:

```
#test data
my $foo = [[1,2,3],[1,5,6],[2,8,9]];

#group elements 1..n by first element
my %bar;
map { $bar{$_->[0]} ||= (); push(@{$bar{$_->[0]}},[@{$_}[1..@$_-1]]) } @$foo;

#lame dump
foreach (keys %bar) {
    print "key: $_\n";
    foreach (@{$bar{$_}}) {
        foreach (@{$_}) {
            print "$_ ";
        }
        print "\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Of course, this solution might only make sense if you need to process each group, and want to do them separately, and might need to make multiple passes.

Answer (score -2):

```
map($keys{$_->[0]} = 1, @raw_list);
foreach $k (keys %keys)
{
 @a = grep($_->[0]==$k,@raw_list);
 # do something with @a;
}
```

Comment: That is even slower than his current code.  His is O(n log n); yours is O(n^2) (because it scans the list once for each key)